# c++ insert in vector of queues

Tags: c++, vector, insert, queue

I'm trying do this to insert a Product in a vector of queues, but it is only filling one by one until the palet of Products is full.

How can I make The method insertion balance the products in storage, and do not fill one by one until the maximum capacity?

Vector of queues:

```
vector < queue <Product*> > depFresh;
```

There exists a heritage between my Deposit class and DepositFresh class. My DepositFresh inherited all the fields declares in my Deposit class.
In my Deposit class  i declared:

```
Class Deposit {
private:
    int number_Palets_Storage;
    int max_Capacity_Palet;
    int total_Area_Deposit;
public:
    virtual void insertProduct(const Produto *produto) =0;
}
```

My class DepositFresh contains the following method:

Method Insert:

```
void DepositFresh::insertProduct(const Product *product) {
        if (depFresh.size() == getNumber_Palets_Storage())
            for (int i = 0; i < depFresh.size(); i++) {
                if (depFresh.at(i).size() < getMax_Capacity__Palet())
                    depFresh.at(i).push(product->clone());
                break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to insert Product into all queues until they are all full ? sound like

```
int i = 0;
while(true)
{
 if (depFresh.at(i).size() < getMax_Capacity__Palet())
                    depFresh.at(i).push(product->clone());
 else
     break;
i = (i + 1) / depFresh.size();
}
```

But why not

```
for(int i = 0; i < depFresh.size(); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < getMax_Capacity__Palet() ; ++j)
       depFresh.at(i).push(product->clone());
```

Comment: Your second example uses should probably use `i` for iteration in one of the loops.

Comment: I'm trying to make The method insertion balance the products in storage, and do not fill one by one until the maximum capacity, because this is already being done in my method.

Comment: @SérgioGomes please explain why my first code example doesn't do just that ?

Answer (score 0):

Imo the easiest is to store new objects in a round robin fashion. To do that you could store an index, which remembers where you last stored something. Once you store something in a queue you can then do something like

`insertion_index = (insertion_index + 1) % v.size();`

On the next call the next queue will store the next product.

This is the most simple balancing strategy one can think of, but it would also be a possibility to use a priority queue instead of the vector to always insert into the queue with the least elements, using the size of the queue as priority (low = high priority).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to insert the product into the lowest capacity queue in your vector.  Why not search the smallest size and push accordingly?

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class myContainer 
{
private:
    std::vector< std::queue< long > > depFresh;
public:
    myContainer( size_t queue_cnt ) : depFresh( queue_cnt )
    {
    }
    void insertProduct( long product )
    {
        auto iter = std::min_element( depFresh.begin(), depFresh.end(), []( std::queue< long > & l, std::queue< long > & r ){ return l.size() < r.size(); } );
        iter->push( product );
    }
    void dump()
    {
        size_t index = 0;
        std::cout << "---------------------------" << std::endl;
        for( const auto & o : depFresh )
        {
            std::cout << ++index << " has size " << o.size() << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << "---------------------------" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myContainer container( 5 );
    for( long x = 0; x < 40; ++x )
    {
        container.insertProduct( x ); 
        container.dump();
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
---------------------------
1 has size 1
2 has size 0
3 has size 0
4 has size 0
5 has size 0
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 1
2 has size 1
3 has size 0
4 has size 0
5 has size 0
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 1
2 has size 1
3 has size 1
4 has size 0
5 has size 0
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 1
2 has size 1
3 has size 1
4 has size 1
5 has size 0
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 1
2 has size 1
3 has size 1
4 has size 1
5 has size 1
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 2
2 has size 1
3 has size 1
4 has size 1
5 has size 1
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 2
2 has size 2
3 has size 1
4 has size 1
5 has size 1
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 2
2 has size 2
3 has size 2
4 has size 1
5 has size 1
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 2
2 has size 2
3 has size 2
4 has size 2
5 has size 1
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 2
2 has size 2
3 has size 2
4 has size 2
5 has size 2
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 3
2 has size 2
3 has size 2
4 has size 2
5 has size 2
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 3
2 has size 3
3 has size 2
4 has size 2
5 has size 2
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 3
2 has size 3
3 has size 3
4 has size 2
5 has size 2
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 3
2 has size 3
3 has size 3
4 has size 3
5 has size 2
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 3
2 has size 3
3 has size 3
4 has size 3
5 has size 3
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 4
2 has size 3
3 has size 3
4 has size 3
5 has size 3
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 4
2 has size 4
3 has size 3
4 has size 3
5 has size 3
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 4
2 has size 4
3 has size 4
4 has size 3
5 has size 3
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 4
2 has size 4
3 has size 4
4 has size 4
5 has size 3
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 4
2 has size 4
3 has size 4
4 has size 4
5 has size 4
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 5
2 has size 4
3 has size 4
4 has size 4
5 has size 4
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 5
2 has size 5
3 has size 4
4 has size 4
5 has size 4
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 5
2 has size 5
3 has size 5
4 has size 4
5 has size 4
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 5
2 has size 5
3 has size 5
4 has size 5
5 has size 4
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 5
2 has size 5
3 has size 5
4 has size 5
5 has size 5
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 6
2 has size 5
3 has size 5
4 has size 5
5 has size 5
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 6
2 has size 6
3 has size 5
4 has size 5
5 has size 5
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 6
2 has size 6
3 has size 6
4 has size 5
5 has size 5
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 6
2 has size 6
3 has size 6
4 has size 6
5 has size 5
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 6
2 has size 6
3 has size 6
4 has size 6
5 has size 6
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 7
2 has size 6
3 has size 6
4 has size 6
5 has size 6
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 7
2 has size 7
3 has size 6
4 has size 6
5 has size 6
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 7
2 has size 7
3 has size 7
4 has size 6
5 has size 6
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 7
2 has size 7
3 has size 7
4 has size 7
5 has size 6
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 7
2 has size 7
3 has size 7
4 has size 7
5 has size 7
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 8
2 has size 7
3 has size 7
4 has size 7
5 has size 7
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 8
2 has size 8
3 has size 7
4 has size 7
5 has size 7
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 8
2 has size 8
3 has size 8
4 has size 7
5 has size 7
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 8
2 has size 8
3 has size 8
4 has size 8
5 has size 7
---------------------------
---------------------------
1 has size 8
2 has size 8
3 has size 8
4 has size 8
5 has size 8
---------------------------
</pre>
```